# UPDATE - CRUD with PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Llevo dos días con este problema, el siguiente código a la hora de ejecutarlo me devuelve: No body returned for response. Necesito una explicación precisa y su respectiva aplicación. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
//UPDATE CLIENT
try{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT')
{
    $db     = new db();
    $dbConn = $db->connect();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("UPDATE client SET   client_name    = :client_name,
                                                  cellphone      = :cellphone, 
                                                  email          = :email, 
                                                  assigned_task  = :assigned_task, 
                                                  remaining_days = :remaining_days
                                            WHERE id             = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    header('200 OK');
    $message = 'Updated User';
    echo json_encode($message);;
    exit();
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = [
        'error' => true,
        'text'  => $e->getMessage()
    ];
}
```

Comment: A la hora de pasarlos estoy haciendo algo mal y no estaría sabiendo como resolverlo. Porque al utilizar **bindValue()** hago lo siguiente, por ejemplo: `stmt->bindValue(':client_name', 'client_name');`. También, intenté con un array asociativo dentro del execute: `stmt->exectute(['client_name' => 'client_name']);` etc. pero aún así nada.

Comment: @Aprendiz porque sino procede a un **Header** y arroja error 400 por defecto , para el código en general

Comment: Este código es diverso de tu anterior pregunta. Aquí la consulta es claramente errónea, porque te está faltando hacer *bind* de los otros valores: `:client_name, :cellphone`, etc. Es decir, tienes que pasar con `bindValue` todos aquellos valores que en la consulta estén indicados con `:identificador`, no solamente el valor del `WHERE`. Pero mi pregunta es, dado que el problema viene de lejos, ¿estás recibiendo bien los datos? ¿Si haces un `var_dump($id);` se muestra el valor del id? ¿Si haces un `var_dump($_GET);` muestra valores?

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo pude resolver!! Anoche pasé el méthodo a **POST** directamente. Con **PUT** no le estaba encontrando la vuelta y al cambiar de método ya no tuve más problemas. Y faltaba agregarle los parámetros en **bindValue**, de `:client_name`, `:cellphone`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//UPDATE CLIENT
$response = array();
try{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT')
{
    $db     = new db();
    $dbConn = $db->connect();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("UPDATE client SET   client_name    = :client_name,
                                                  cellphone      = :cellphone, 
                                                  email          = :email, 
                                                  assigned_task  = :assigned_task, 
                                                  remaining_days = :remaining_days
                                            WHERE id             = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    header('200 OK');
    $message = 'Updated User';
    $response = array( 'text' => $message, 'error' => false );
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
    $response = array( 'error' => true, 'text' => $e->getMessage() );
}

echo json_encode( $response );
exit();
```

El problema es que si el controlador de la base falla, estas creando un arreglo con un error, pero jamás se está mostrando, es decir no hay un `echo`, si sale bien. Para resolverlo se crea una variable fuera del scope `try-catch` y sin importar donde caiga, siempre habrá una respuesta.

Espero te puedas ayudar con esto. No tengo un ambiente de desarrollo pero no creo que sea difícil depurarlo para ti.